# Lazy loading in EF does not work

Tags: .net, entity-framework, loading, lazy-evaluation

I again have the following two classes, that are generated by my test model:

```
public partial class House
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public House()
    {
        this.Persons = new HashSet<Person>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}


public partial class Person
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string namen { get; set; }
    public int house { get; set; }

    public virtual House House1 { get; set; }
}
```

In the constructor of my DBContext I explicitly enable Lazy Loading, what should not even be necessary:

```
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
```

Later I call a list of houses:

```
        YardEntities cx = new YardEntities();
        IList<House> hl = cx.Houses.ToList<House>();
        House h = hl[0];
        ///**************BREAKPOINT*******************///
        Person g = h.Persons.First<Person>();
        output = g.namen;
```

After the marked breakpoint I expected, that all the persons associated with the houses are *not* loaded at this point because of lazy loading. I did not access a single person so why should they be loaded? However they are loaded, because my debugger shows me all the name attributes.

Can somebody explain this behaviour? Why is Lazy loading not working?

Comment: i think because u are using a .. cx.Houses.ToList<House>();   do not do a toList() and you will nog get the data

Comment: No- this is the official tutorial and it also uses tolist() http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx

Comment: to humor me, try without the tolist

Comment: Without tolist it also loads all entities. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I did not access a single person so why should they be loaded?

You are right. lazy loading won't load any relation unless you want to **access** them.

> However they are loaded, because my **debugger** shows me all the name attributes.

well here actually your **debugger** wants to **access** them, so lazy loading will do the work and get them from database.

Comment: ah okay. Well, if thats true Im fine.

Comment: Yes, it's true. If you want to confirm that lazy loading is working as expected, try [logging the database operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx) instead to confirm that the relation only gets loaded (queried) on first access.

Comment: Okay, I tried that and I can verify that it is 100% true. Thanks that answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

If I do not use tolist():

```
        DbSet<House> hl = cx.Houses;
        House h = hl.FirstOrDefault<House>();
```

h contains all persons even though lazy loading is enabled. I guess that Arvins answer must be true. The debugger loads all the values when I want to see them. 
But is there a way to proof his guess?